# Error while entering data in a class properties in matlab

Tags: matlab, class, properties, public

I have made following class in matlab.

```
classdef details
%   SCORES Summary of this class goes here
%   Class for stroring the individual scores array of each of the
%   comparison of the models and the test files including the number of
%   coefficients used and number of gaussian 

properties(SetAccess=public)
    name;
    rollno=0;
    batch=0;
    branch;
    image;
end

methods
end
end
```

and i am accessing it in following way

```
detail=details;
detail.name=get(handles.edit2,'string');
detail.rollno=str2num(get(handles.edit3,'string'));
```

On running the program its giving following error:

??? No public field rollno exists for class details.

I don't know where is the error??????

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same problem as you, and I think I've found the cause.  If you have a variable in the MATLAB workspace that is defined by the class, you cannot change it.  That is, you probably have a test variable that is a "details" class, and was initialized before you added the "rollno" propriety.  Try deleting any test variables.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this

```
properties(public)
```

to this

```
properties(SetAccess = public)
```

See the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/defining-properties.html) for more info

Comment: problem still persists even after making specified changes.

Comment: what do you see when you type `which details` at the matlab command prompt?  Does it show the filename where your `classdef details` lives?

Comment: it shows this:
D:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\MATLAB\details.m  % details constructor

Comment: I have created dis 'classdef details' in a file named details.m and i am accessing it from a different m file in same path.

Comment: This works fine for me when I copy your code and do exactly what you describe.  Maybe you should update your question with the following details: Operating System, Matlab Version, and some more context of the call to `detail.rollno` that is giving you errors.  For example, is it part of a script, part of a function, part of a subfunction, etc.?  Without more information, I am out of ideas.

Comment: I am using Matlab version 7.5.0.342(R2007b) on Windows 7 pc.
I am creating and accessing my class object from a GUI button function.

Comment: I recommend that you update your question with this information.  You aren't getting any bites as is.  Your Matlab version is pretty old, but I have no way of telling whether that is the cause of the problem or not.